# Exception in thread "main" com.oracle.bmc.model.BmcException: (404, NamespaceNotFound, false)

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

I executed the OCI sample program ObjectStorageGetBucketExample.java and was able to create the bucket and add the file.  But, when I ran the ObjectStorageAsyncExample.java and ObjectStorageSyncExample.java to list the bucket.  I got the following errors:

> Exception in thread "main" com.oracle.bmc.model.BmcException: (404,
>   NamespaceNotFound, false) You do not have the authorization to perform
>   this request, or the requested resource could not be found.

I can write but can't read.  I just want to know what type of authorization do I need?

Here is the full errors:

Exception in thread "main" com.oracle.bmc.model.BmcException: (404, NamespaceNotFound, false) You do not have authorization to perform this request, or the requested resource could not be found
at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.ResponseHelper.throwIfNotSuccessful(ResponseHelper.java:138)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.ResponseConversionFunctionFactory$ValidatingParseResponseFunction.apply(ResponseConversionFunctionFactory.java:88)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.ResponseConversionFunctionFactory$ValidatingParseResponseFunction.apply(ResponseConversionFunctionFactory.java:84)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.internal.http.ListBucketsConverter$1.apply(ListBucketsConverter.java:112)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.internal.http.ListBucketsConverter$1.apply(ListBucketsConverter.java:94)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.lambda$null$52(ObjectStorageClient.java:1222)
    at com.oracle.bmc.retrier.BmcGenericRetrier.doFunctionCall(BmcGenericRetrier.java:88)
    at com.oracle.bmc.retrier.BmcGenericRetrier.lambda$execute$0(BmcGenericRetrier.java:59)
    at com.oracle.bmc.waiter.GenericWaiter.execute(GenericWaiter.java:55)
    at com.oracle.bmc.retrier.BmcGenericRetrier.execute(BmcGenericRetrier.java:50)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.lambda$listBuckets$53(ObjectStorageClient.java:1218)
    at com.oracle.bmc.retrier.BmcGenericRetrier.doFunctionCall(BmcGenericRetrier.java:88)
    at com.oracle.bmc.retrier.BmcGenericRetrier.lambda$execute$0(BmcGenericRetrier.java:59)
    at com.oracle.bmc.waiter.GenericWaiter.execute(GenericWaiter.java:55)
    at com.oracle.bmc.retrier.BmcGenericRetrier.execute(BmcGenericRetrier.java:50)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.listBuckets(ObjectStorageClient.java:1212)
    at ObjectStorageSyncExample.main(ObjectStorageSyncExample.java:47)

Comment: Hi - can you please include the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @Joe, I have added the full details of the error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though it is attempting to list buckets. The ListBuckets operation requires BUCKET_INSPECT permission.

https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Identity/Reference/objectstoragepolicyreference.htm

Permissions are granted via IAM policies. And BUCKET_INSPECT can be granted explicitly, but is also included in `inspect buckets` and `inspect object-family`.

hope this helps!